# Fourier transform of odd function equals zero.

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

This question is about whether the Fourier transform of an odd function equals zero, if and only if the odd function equals zero.

Edit: in my course we only tackle functions so that there exists a finite row of $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$ so that f(x) is continuous over $(-\infty,x_1)$, $(x_1,x_2)$, ..., $(x_n,+\infty)$. And the integrals over these intervals are all finite. My professor called these type of functions "Riemann-integrable".

After I rewrote the equation I stumbled on how to prove that if
$$ i\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} sin(2\pi k x)\cdot f(x) dx=0$$ for a function $f(x)$, $f(x)$ not depending on $k$ and for every $k \in $ $R$, (real numbers) then $f(x)$ must equal zero.

What I tried to do, was to show that if it holds for $k=k_0$ then $\delta \in R$ and I tried to show that :$$ i\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} sin(2\pi (k_0+\delta) x)\cdot f(x) dx=0$$

$$ i\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} sin(2\pi k_0 x)\cdot cos(2\pi \delta \cdot x)\cdot f(x) +cos(2\pi k_0 x)\cdot sin(2\pi \delta x)\cdot f(x)dx=0$$

However this only seems to complicate the problem even more.

Comment: For "every function" would mean? The Fourier transform is e.g. an isometry on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, hence $\mathcal F u = 0$ implies $u=0$, nevermind if the function was known to be odd beforehand or not.

Comment: I edited it, should be “a” function and I think you are indeed correct since I just have to apply the inverse fourier transform to both the fourier transform of 0 and 0.

Comment: My question is, stated more explicitly, what kind of function are we allowing ourselves to Fourier transform? $L^2$ functions? Schwartz functions? continuous with compact support...?

Comment: You have to be more precise about the type of function you are allowed to use because the statement is wrong for a function like $f(x) = \boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q^+_0}(x) -  \boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q^-_0}(x)$.

Comment: @Falcon what are these sets $\mathbb Q^\pm_0$, I have never seen them (at least in these clothes) in my entire mathematical life

Comment: @CalvinKhor I made an edit to hopefully specify what type of functions we are using.

Comment: $\mathbb Q^\pm_0 := \mathbb R^\pm_0 \cap \mathbb Q$.